# Question about Abstract Algebra Notation for Abelian Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, notation, abelian-groups

I've never used this forum before but I had a question about the formatting of one my homework problems.

Prove: If $H$ is an Abelian subgroup of a group $G$, then $\langle H, Z(G)\rangle$ is an Abelian group.

I suppose my confusion is with the use of generator notation containing two arguments.

I understand that the problem is essentially asking me to show if we have an Abelian subgroup $H$ and the center of $G,$ some combination of their elements must be Abelian.

In some kind of psuedo-proof logic:

1. We know for all $x,y$ in $H$, $xy=yx$
2. We know for all $x$ in $Z(G)$ and all $y$ in $G$, $xy=yx$

Is $\langle H, Z(G)\rangle$ a generator for a group with elements that are pairs $(x,y)$?

Thank you in advance if you can help me in any way. I looked through D&F and online but wasn't able to find much or wasn't equipped mentally to know what to look for.

Comment: I imagine that the notation $<H,Z(G)>$ means the subgroup generated by the elements of $H$ and the elements of $Z(G).$ Equivalently this is the smallest subgroup of $G$ containing both $H$ and $Z(G).$

Comment: It's the subgroup generated by $H\cup Z(G)$. In this case it's the same as $H\cdot Z(G)=\{xy:x\in H,\,y\in Z(G)\}$.

Comment: $\langle S\rangle$ is the subgroup generated by a set $S\subseteq G.$ $\langle S,T\rangle$ is just another name for $\langle S\cup T\rangle.$ If $g_1,\dots,g_k\in G,$ then $\langle g_1,\dots,g_k\rangle$ is just shorthand for $\langle \{g_1,\dots,g_k\}\rangle.$

Comment: Sometimes that notation means the join of $H$ and $Z(G)$.

Answer (score 2):

This is a slightly more rigorous look at how you’d prove this.

Given any group $G$ and $S\subseteq G,$ we can define $\langle S\rangle$ as the smallest subgroup of $H$ which contains $S.$ “Smallest” is a bit vague, but we can write it as:

> Let$$G_S=\{H\mid H\text{ a subgroup of }G\text{ and }S\subseteq H\}.$$ This set is non-empty since $G\in G_S.$
> Then define $$\langle S\rangle =\bigcap_{H\in G_S} H$$
> Any intersection of subgroups of $G$ is a subgroup of $G.$

This definition has a drawback. It is hard to prove things about $\langle S\rangle.$

We have an equivalent inductive definition:

> Given $S,$ define $$S_0=\{1\}\cup S\cup \{s^{-1}\mid s\in S\}$$ and then recursively: $$S_{n+1}=\{s_1s_2\mid s_1,s_2\in S_n\}$$ Since $1\in S_0,$ we get $S_n\subseteq S_{n+1}.$ Then define: $$\langle S\rangle =\bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty} S_n$$

You can prove this subset of $G$ is a group, because you can prove inductively that if $s\in S_n$ then $s^{-1}\in S_n,$ and if $s_1\in S_m, s_2\in S_n$ then $s_1s_2\in S_{\max(m,n)+1}.$

This second definition is more intuitive if you call $\langle S\rangle$ the subgroup “generated by $S.$” We see it “generated” step by step.

You can also prove this is equivalent to the first definition by showing that if $S\subseteq H$ for some subgroup $H$ then, inductively, each $S_n\subseteq H,$ so $\langle S\rangle \subseteq H.$

This second definition is how you’ll prove $\langle H,Z(G)\rangle=\langle H\cup Z(G)\rangle$ is abelian.

More generally:

> If every pair of elements $s_1,s_2\in S$ commute, then $\langle S\rangle$ is abelian.

The proof of this is to prove it inductively for any $s_1,s_2\in S_n.$ Note the base case $n=0$ requres a tiny bit of work because you have deal with the inverses. Not hard, but some work.

The induction step is relatively easy.

You’ve already proved every pair of elements of $S=H\cup Z(G)$ commutes, so you are done.

Comment: Would this formalization be typical of what's expected in an intro to abstract algebra class, or is it just a more rigorous formalization of the same hypothesis? Either way, I appreciate the depth of the answer and insights on how I could prove it in other ways.

Comment: @Pengu9n I’d hope not. But it is the heart of the proper proof. Not sure how to phrase it less formally, myself.

Comment: It's not so hard to use the first definition once you get used to it.  For example, start out by proving the set of elements of $G$ which commute with every element of $H$ is a subgroup which contains $H \cup Z(G)$, and therefore, it contains $\langle H, Z(G) \rangle$.  And then similarly, prove that the set of elements of $G$ which commute with every element of $\langle H, Z(G) \rangle$ is a subgroup which contains $H \cup Z(G)$, so it must contain $\langle H, Z(G) \rangle$.  Recasting that last statement gives you exactly what you wanted.

Comment: It's probably especially easy to use the first definition if you think of it as an induction-type principle: suppose you have some proposition $P$ defined on elements of $G$.  Furthermore, suppose (i) base case: $P(x)$ whenever $x \in S$; (ii) induction step 1: whenever $P(x)$ and $P(y)$, then $P(xy)$; (iii) induction step 2: whenever $P(x)$, then also $P(x^{-1})$.  Then for every $x \in \langle S \rangle$, we have $P(x)$.  (Proof: you've shown $\{ x \in G \mid P(x) \}$ is a subgroup of $G$ which contains $S$.)

Comment: Whoops, I missed base case 2: $P(e)$ where $e$ is the identity element of $G$.  (Though note that if $S$ is nonempty, then necessarily the other conditions will imply $P(e)$.)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all so much.
Here was my first stab at this proof.

Let G be a group.

Let H be an Abelian subgroup of G.

By the definition of the center of a group, Z(G) = {x∈G|∀y∈G (xy=yx)}

The generator <H, Z(G)> = <H ∪ Z(G)> = H ∪ Z ∪ {hz | h∈H, z∈Z(G)}

Let x,y ∈ H. Because H ≤ G, x,y ∈ G.

Any element z∈Z(G) commutes with all elements of G => zx = xz and zy=yz

Because all elements in the set generated by <H, Z(G)> commute, then <H, Z(G)> is Abelian.

Comment: A formal proof would note that $J=\{hz\mid h\in H,z\in Z(G)\}$ must be a subset of  $\langle S\cup Z(G)\rangle.$ But then show $J$ is a group, so it must be all of $\langle H,Z(G)\rangle.$

Comment: You don’t need to separate out $H\cup Z\cup$ from the set, since they are in $\{hz\}.$